# "Select Version" is empty after successfully installed and setup Apache Ambari from source

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I managed to build, install and setup Apache Ambari successfully on my Debian 10 machine.

I am able to launch the Ambari admin UI and see the wizard.

However in the second step **Select Version** of the wizard, I see no choice to select:

[image]

What am I suppose to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you resolve your issue?
I'm currently facing the exact same situation and don't know how to continue.

Comment: Any solution for this @Muffex

Comment: Tbh I was not able to resolve my issue. Which is why I chose to use the version from the official (deprecated) repository.

Comment: sadly, the `hadoop`
-community on SO seems to be pretty much inactive

Answer (score 0):

@wxh You need to install a Stack Repository in order to provide ambari with components and services to install.   For example: HDP2 or HDP3 or HDF.

Debian10 repositories are not build, but you can try the Debian 9 ones:

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.3.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/hdp_31_repositories.html

If you are installing from source you may not want to use HDP/HDF which opens up a huge can of worms for making your own stack.

Comment: Yes I was installing from source. I decided to move away from this Hadoop ecosystem because of exactly what u said. Open source doesn't always mean free.

Comment: I believe Open Source should be free, but Good Support isn't free....  and that's their business model like many others.  I am actually working on a free Demo Data Platform that would be the next step for your ambari install.